# Hide bottom panel after task runner

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using the task runner to run my file, my configuration prompts me to "Press any key to close the terminal".

This will close the newly created terminal, but the bottom panel remains open with my focus on the bottom terminal. I end up pressing command+J to close it and refocus on my file.

Is there a way for that "Press any key" to both close the newly created terminal and close the bottom panel, returning me to the file?

Comment: with `runCommands` construct a key binding for space `when` `terminalHasFocus`, send space to terminal and call the command bound to `Cmd+J` (`Ctrl+J`)